# format not rendering in starship

Tags: windows, powershell, customization

i am trying to customize my prompt using [starship](https://starship.rs/) but the prompt doesn't seem to render battery status

```ini
# Get editor completions based on the config schema
#"$schema" = 'https://starship.rs/config-schema.json'

# Inserts a blank line between shell prompts
add_newline = true

format = """ $directory$package $cmd_duration
$battery $character"""

[character]
success_symbol = "[❯](bold green)" # The "success_symbol" segment is being set to "➜" with the color "bold green"
error_symbol = "[✘](bold green)"

# Disable the package module, hiding it from the prompt completely
[package]
disabled = false
```

[image: terminal]

Comment: Is your battery below 10%? Because apparently [that's the default threshold for showing anything](https://starship.rs/config/#battery).

Comment: @IMSoP i get it now. i need to set threshold for every level to display it. 
it now perfectly renders the format. thx for the help!

Comment: @IMSoP do you know how can i change the color of the path?